# Set sheet only part of a sheet name to a interer

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I was wondering if there was a way that I can set only a certain part of a sheet name as a Integer.

Examples: Sheet names

S_Report

Rf_Report

I would need to select everything be for _Report and set it as a Integer.

I already have the code to select the worksheet but I am not sure how to select a Certain part of the name.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do? change the worksheet name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to obtain, but I am guessing that you either want to change the sheet name or return the text before "_Report".

If you want to ***change the name*** of the active sheet, you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "1_Report"
```

If you want to ***return the text*** before "_Report" (in this case in a MsgBox) you can use

```
MsgBox Mid(ActiveSheet.Name, 1, InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1)
```

Comment: Yea i Want to return text but set the return text as a string so i later can call that up and put it in a text box

Comment: You can save the text in a string variable, say `ReturnedText`, by stating `ReturnedText = Mid(ActiveSheet.Name, 1, InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much here it is k = Mid(ActiveSheet.Name, 1, InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1) This works great